# Hosted APEX 5.0 (apex.oracle.com) - Webservice Reference

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to do a testcase dealing with webservice REST in hosted Ape 5.0 Environment (apex.oracle.com).

There is a preinstalled Web Service in the Workspace "oracle.example.hr".

I have managed to call that Service from my Browsers URL.

But when i create a Web Service Reference to use that Service for an APEX Page, I receive the Errors:

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

I am using the Oracle hosted Environment apex.oracle.com; thus I cannot apply ACLs etc.

Any suggestions?

Kind Regards,
Andreas Resch

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the code that is calling the service?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https?
It seems that you are using a client that checks if the certificates are valid.
You can either solve the problem on the server (that is not configured with the correct certificate or configure the client to ignore this problem).